# keyboard shortcuts in a ul tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<ul>` created with PHP:

```
$WORLD_STATES =
     array(
        "France",
        "Germany", 
        "Greece",
        "Greenland",
        "United Kingdom",
        "United States", 
        "Uruguay"
     );

echo '<ul>';
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($WORLD_STATES); $i++){
    echo '<li rel="' . $WORLD_STATES[$i] . '">'.$WORLD_STATES[$i].'</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Since the full list of countries is very long, with a scrollbar in a div tag, I want the user to be able to reach a country by simply pressing an alphabetic keyboard shortcut.

How can I accomplish this?

this is an image:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to use a client-side script to achieve this, would JavaScript, jQuery, Prototype, Glow, MooTools...be acceptable? (If so, which one(s)?)

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with your question. POST here HTML code instead **(shortened** to the few items) and then ask for the solution.

Comment: @David but how can I do this with javascript?

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using a select element (dropdown), which browsers natively support keyboard shortcut on ?

Comment: I've built my own select which looks perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with jQuery (jQuery suggested as an easy/reliable way to abstract away cross-browser inconsistencies), I suggest adding a search box to the beginning of the list, giving the following:

#### html:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="search" id="search" /></li>
    <li>Armenia</li>
    <li>Belgium</li>
    <li>China</li>
    <li>Denmark</li>
    <li>Estonia</li>
    <li>France</li>
    <li>Germany</li>
    <li>Holland</li>
    <li>Ireland</li>
    <li>Japan</li>
    <li>Luxembourg</li>
    <li>Monaco</li>
    <li>Netherlands</li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('#search').keyup(
    function(e){
        var string = $(this).val();
        if (string.length > 0){
            $('ul li:contains(' + string + ')')
                .addClass('result');
            $('.result')
                .not(':contains('+ string + ')')
                .removeClass('result');
        }
        else {
            $('.result').removeClass('result');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zPqpu/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need client side script.

You could add the [`accesskey`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key) attribute to an `a` node, and point the `href` attribute to the unordered list.

Users would still need modifiers though, but it's the standard way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `<select>` element instead?

For example:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
   <option>United States</option>
   <option>United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

The `<select>` element has the sort of alphanumeric jump functionality built in. You could have a dropdown with all of your countries, with a submit button instead.

If you're using your list to jump to a new page, then you could just read the value of `$_POST['country']` and redirect to whichever page it applies to.

If instead you're just using it to jump to some other location on the page, you run some javascript when the form is submitted, read the value of the select, and jump to that location on the page.

Comment: good question, I've built a select like component(my personal taste) and I used a div+ul+input text+ a button (you can see it in the photo)

Comment: @Simo: You realize that you can style `<select>` and `<option>` with CSS, right? For example, I made [this](http://imgur.com/cgUGI) quickly as a proof of concept. If you play around a bit, you can probably make yours look just as good as the one you made out of `<div>` elements.

Comment: @AgentConundrum yes true, but the one I show you in the image, when you click in the text input (which is readonly) the list will appear in a fadeIn manner(just like a styled pop up) not like a select element.

Comment: @Simo: Why can't you fade in the `<option>` elements in the same way?

Comment: the fact is that I've done it from scratch :-) I can't distroy what I've been working on all yesterday :)

Comment: @AgentConundrum : to learn more, sometimes , it's good idea to reinvente the wheel. :)

Comment: @Simo: "I can't distroy what I've been working on all yesterday" - you really need to unlearn that. A lot of good design is throwing away code. That's what refactoring is all about. If you fall in love with every line of code you write, you'll end up with a lot of bad legacy code.

Comment: @Simo: I'm all for reinventing the wheel, and it *is* a good learning experience, but if you reinvent a wheel and it turns out to be worse than a normal wheel, it's ok to throw it away.

Comment: @AgentConundrum I'm okey with that, +1

Comment: @agentConundrum the select tag, I've used it in the birth date field. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without changing your current layout using jQuery. Here is crude example:

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    $("#Container li").each(function (index) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.length > 0 && text.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase())
        {
            $("#Container").scrollTop($(this).position().top);
            break;
        }           
    });
});
```

This should scroll the DIV to the position of the `<li>` strarting with the typed letter.